# scipy.stats - get a lognormal's underlying mu and sigma

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

In Python's scipy.stats library, it has a very stylized set of random variable classes, methods, and attributes.  Most relate to the distribution itself, e.g., "what is the mean?" or "what is the variance?"

The lognormal distribution is an oddball because the parameters that define it are not the usual parameters for the distribution, but the parameters for a normal distribution that it derives from.  Simply put, if X is a normal distribution with mean mu and stdev sigma, Y=e^X is a lognormal that has its own means, mode, variance, stdev, etc.

Does anyone know of a quick or clever way to recover the underlying mu and sigma (of the normal distribution X) via methods or attributes of a 'frozen' RV in scipy.stats?

Since scipy.stats does give the mean, stdev, etc., of the actual lognormal, one could do a lot of algebra and recover it from the standard translations...but the code is likely unmaintainable.

For reference< see:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Answer (score -1):

(This post is a bit old but is worth mentioning the answer).

Scipy `rv_continuous` instances have the `.stats` method (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.stats.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.stats)). You can retrieve parameters like mean and variance with this method.

This method can be called from the class or the instance:

```
# from the classs
scipy.stats.lognorm.stats(loc=2,s=1,moments='mvsk')
>> (array(3.64872127), array(4.67077427), array(6.18487714), array(110.93639218))

# or from the instance
scipy.stats.lognorm(loc=2, s=1).stats(moments='mvsk')
```

Comment: This gives the mean and standard deviation of the lognorm distribution, not the normal distribution from which the lognorm is derived, which are the `mu` and `sigma` required by most other stats libraries.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the `mu` and `sigma` very easily from the SciPy `scale` and `shape` parameters:

```
mu = log(scale)
sigma = shape
```

However if you have a non-zero `loc` you need to use this as an offset when doing anything with this distribution. e.g.

```
percentile = mylognorm.cdf(x - loc)

x = mylognorm.inverseCdf(percentile) + loc
```