# Calculate mean and sigma of the underlying normal distribution of a lognormal distribution

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I'm fitting a lognormal function to lognormal distributed data with the following code using [scipy.stats.lognormal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html):

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm 
params = lognorm.fit(data, loc=0)
```

I get back three parameters. Now I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution. I know that I've to use the parameters I get back from `scipy` but I'm not sure how to make the calculation on these. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8747761) question is almost what I'm looking for but they calculate the mean and stddev of the lognormal and not the underlying normal distribution.

*Edit:*

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51617073) post where is done what I need, except that there is no `scipy` `loc` parameter included. In my case I want to keep this parameter during my conversation into mean and stddev.

Comment: FYI: You used `loc=0`, but I suspect you meant to use `floc=0` to fix the location parameter to be 0.

Comment: I did use `loc` as `floc` is not mentioned on the scipy site I linked. And indeed when I use `floc=0` I get different results for my fit, but they are not as good as when using `loc=0`.

Comment: They are not as good because they use only two parameters instead of three.  Typically, the log-normal distribution does not include the "location" parameter (called `loc` in SciPy).  If the three parameter version is the correct model for your data, then use it, but be aware that when most folks talk about the log-normal distribution, they are referring to the two parameter distribution.

Comment: I did some research to find literature about this 3-parameter model used in `scipy` but wasn't able to find something. Is this approach documented somewhere outside of `scipy`?

Comment: *All* the continuous univariate distributions in SciPy are parametrized as [location-scale families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family): they have the location parameter `loc`, the scale parameter `scale`, and zero or more shape parameters.  Changing the location parameter gives a translation of the distribution.  Note that for the log-normal distribution, the mean of the underlying normal distribution is not a location parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got this correct. With your last sentence do you want to say that when I'm converting the `shape` and `scale` parameter of the lognormal distribution into mu and sigma of this lognormal distribution this is independent from the `loc` parameter so it can be ignored?

Comment: I answered a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74575196/659612